# Using Packery with Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, packery

This is my first Stack Overflow question!

I am building a Pinterest clone with Rails and using Packery for the index page; I want to be able to move around posts on the page and Packery seems like the tool for the job. I installed Packery with Bower and included it in my application.js file

```
//= require packery/dist/packery.pkgd.min.js
```

Below that, I have this block of code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.grid').imagesLoaded(function() {
    $('.grid').packery({
      itemSelector: '.grid-item'
    });
  })
});
```

When I run the page, the layout flows just like Masonry does, but I can't drag and drop the images (all stored in a  with a class of ".grid-item"). Am I missing something? I am using Bootstrap as well, for what that's worth.

Thanks!

Comment: Any JS errors in your console?

Comment: No, no errors, everything's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s easy to miss, but the documentation page [Packery – Draggable](http://packery.metafizzy.co/draggable.html) is linked in Packery’s intro paragraph like this:

> Elements can be … [dragged around](http://packery.metafizzy.co/draggable.html).

That documentation page seems to indicate that you need to include an external library to add draggability. For example, you can use the library it recommends, [Draggabilly](http://draggabilly.desandro.com/), by installing it with Bower and including it with Sprockets like you’ve done with Packery, then using this JS:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.grid').imagesLoaded(function() {
    $('.grid').packery({
      itemSelector: '.grid-item',
      // columnWidth helps with drop positioning
      columnWidth: 100
    });

    $grid.find('.grid-item').each( function( i, gridItem ) {
      var draggie = new Draggabilly( gridItem );
      $grid.packery( 'bindDraggabillyEvents', draggie );
    });
  })
});
```

See [that documentation page](http://packery.metafizzy.co/draggable.html) for some CSS that you should also add.

Comment: So that worked! I can drag the div around. But now a new problem popped up. I'm using Bootstrap as well and it was using col-md-4 and had three columns of images; now with Packery, it's defaulting to two columns. Any reason why?

Comment: Never mind, figured it out! It's that columnWidth line that I didn't have originally. Thank you for the help!